# How to format the following dialogue without the parenthesis?

Tags: creative-writing, dialogue

So the protagonist's boyfriend committed suicide. He left a suicide note. And now the detective is showing it to the protagonist:

> "So *I'm* the one who made him do it?
>
> "We read the letter. (Apologies. Standard procedures). Nothing inside
>   suggests that. In fact, Tom didn't leave a reason."

How can I restructure the dialogue so I doesn't use the parentheses?

Comment: Is the detective supposed to actually be saying those things? If so, try using dialogues tags.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Add a little stage direction.

> "We read the letter." She had the grace to look a little shamefaced. "Apologies. Standard procedure." He nodded, even if his heart hurt a little to think the cops had read Tom's note. "Nothing inside suggests you're to blame. In fact, Tom didn't leave a reason."